# Clickable drop down menu using jinja and flask

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

I am very much new to Front end design. I am basically using Flask
as the backend. My use case is as follows.

(1) I am reading bunch of alerts from MySQL database and displaying each alert record as html link.
    Following is the sample code in Flask html page:

```
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    {% for n in my_list %}
    <li><a href={{n}}</a>{{n}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
```

(2) For every alert which is displayed as html link, i wanted the following:
     (a) Display some message when we hover the mouse over each of the html alert links.
     (b) Every alert html link should have some kind of clickable drop down menu with couple of actions
         displayed when we click any html alert link.

Comment: for the second requirement, what you want to display when hovered on a link. and what should be the values in the dropdown? also what all have you tried till now?

Comment: I tried the following code, but it did not work. "{% for n in my_list %}
        <li> <a href={{n}}</a>title="hover text" {{n}}</li>
        {% endfor %}"

Comment: This should work for you. `"{% for n in my_list %} <li> <a href={{n}} title="hover text"> {{n}} </a></li> {% endfor %}"`